# Order rows by IN

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT collateral.*
FROM collateral
WHERE collateral.id IN (85,565,32,33)
```

Is there away that I can get the query results to output in the `ORDER BY` the `IN` value rather that by `ASC`, which appears to be default?

By default the query outputs the results in the following order

```
row    id
---------
1      32
2      33
3      85
4     565
```

What I'd like to achieve is ordering based on the order of the values in the `IN` value

```
row    id
---------
1      86
2     565
3      32
4      33
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order by field`

```
WHERE collateral.id IN (85,565,32,33)
order by field(collateral.id ,85,565,32,33)
```

Comment: @onebitrocket I dont see your +1 ...

Answer (score 0):

For databases lacking "field" (or similar) function the answer is

```
WHERE collateral.id IN (85,565,32,33)
ORDER BY CASE 
   WHEN collateral.id = 85  THEN 1
   WHEN collateral.id = 565 THEN 2
   WHEN collateral.id = 32  THEN 3
   WHEN collateral.id = 33  THEN 4
END
```

For MySql use @Abhik answer